# Get a list of users on a Google Apps domain

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace, google-provisioning-api, google-directory-api

We have an app in the Google Apps Marketplace (the new one, i.e. using OAuth2) which needs to get a list of users in the domain.

We're currently using the Provisioning API for this (which we know is deprecated, but there seems to be no better option). Lately however, we're starting to get "You are not authorized to access this API" 403's, for some domains.

- Does anyone know why we're suddendly getting 403's, a bug perhaps? There seem to be some other bugs as well, for example the scope https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly doesn't work, but https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/ does.
- Does anyone know when it will be possible to start using the new Admin SDK Directory API to get a list of users? This isn't possible now because even when an administrator installs the app, it would only work if they go to their domain security settings and manually check "Enable API Access", see the related question here: [How can I access user info on a domain without the domain administrator enabling API access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846098/how-can-i-access-user-info-on-a-domain-without-the-domain-administrator-enabling)

Comment: Dumb question...did you enable the Admin SDK for use? I coped a project once and forgot to turn on the specific APIs and I believe I was getting 403 errors.

Comment: The 403 errors occured using the Provisioning API, not the Admin SDK. It just suddenly stopped working. After a few days the errors stopped though, so probably just a temporary glitch in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start using Admin SDK Directory API. The question you linked to was regarding the case where an admin explicitly disables API access. When they install and an app, we re-enable that setting and let them know.

Not sure about the 403s but that is an older API that is replaced by the Admin SDK.

Comment: Thanks, good to know API access is automatically enabled after installing an app using the new Directory API.

Comment: Are you sure the API access is automatically enabled? I tried it and it wasn't. I couldn't find any documentation about such a feature. Do you have a pointer to a documentation explaining how it works?

Comment: I don't think Admin SDK is automatically enabled for marketplace apps like the provisioning API was. I reported an issue about this a while back, but AFAIK it's still an issue. You have to gracefully deal with the fact that the directory API may not be available for a domain.

Comment: Enabling Admin SDK Directory API in the project doesn't seem to turn on API access for the domain. The admin of the domain needs to explicitly turn on API access.