# Bad deprecation of api for listing users of a domain in google apps for business application

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

I have been using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/ to list all users of a domain when the admin installed my web application.

This api has been deprecated for a while and is now disabled. We are advised to use the new directory api.

However, in order to use the directory api, the admin of the domain must have enabled the api access with a checkbox in a deep menu item. It goes without saying that many of them will have the admin api access disabled.

1) On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846098/how-can-i-access-user-info-on-a-domain-without-the-domain-administrator-enabling/19860097#19860097) Arun Nagarajan said "We are looking into improving this flow" in 2013. Is there any update about this?

2) In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476228/get-a-list-of-users-on-a-google-apps-domain), jonathanberi seems to say that the admin api is automatically enabled when the user installs the app. But I wasn't able to reproduce this feature, and I can't find any documentation stating this. Is there any (preferably official) documentation that confirms such behaviour?